# Return xml data from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query.

```
SELECT convert(xml, A.[business_line]).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)')
from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
```

I am getting an error while running this query.

Error states

```
Msg 9413, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 30, A string literal was expected
```

A.business_line has 2 set of values.

```
1) <collection><object parentid="ce57cc75-3966-478f-bf25-5e3abf716f96" parenttype="Object"><fields><field name="code"><value>BL3</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL2</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL5</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL1</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL6</value></field></fields></object></collection>

2) <collection><object parentid="ce57cc75-3966-478f-bf25-5e3abf716f96" parenttype="Object"><fields/></object></collection>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: As per my comments on your other question, you'll have to check every value in `A.[business_line]`, depending on how many rows you have you may be able to do that manually using an online XML validator, or you may need to find some automated way to do it. Unfortunately no one will be able to tell you what is wrong without seeing the data.

Comment: If you use the manual test code from my other answer i.e. `declare @Test...` to test both of those, what do you get?

Comment: If I do that it gives me correct value. For 1st data it provide BL2 and for 2nd data it provides' NULL' @DaleBurrell

Comment: Exactly, so the data you have shown isn't identical to whats actually in your database.

Comment: Yes Maybe.. Because there are more than 1000 rows.

Comment: <collection><object parentid="ce57cc75-3966-478f-bf25-5e3abf716f96" parenttype="Object"><fields><field name="code"><value>BL3</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL2</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL5</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL1</value></field><field name="code"><value>BL6</value></field></fields></object></collection>

Comment: I found this also.. So it provides BL3 as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [try_convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead. but if you have sql server 2012 up.

```
SELECT try_convert(xml, A.[business_line]).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)')
from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
```

applying on your original query.

```
select try_convert(xml, col).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)') 
from (
    select col= Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[business_line], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') 
    from [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A) t1
```

Comment: A last help needed. When I append it into a query. It is showing me error in syntax. Please see my below query.

Comment: Declare @Query as nvarchar(1000)
 Set @Query='set nocount on;


Select Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[type], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') as Type,
try_convert(xml, col).value('(/collection/object/fields/field/value)[1]', 'varchar(3)') 
from (
    select col= Coalesce(replace(replace(A.[business_line], char(10), ''''), char(13), ''''),'''') 
 FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A'

Comment: @metal Can you assist if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: Error I am getting is ---- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '/'.

Comment: @NikhilKotian, please create separate for this issue.

Comment: ok..I can only after 90 minutes. Stack overflow policy it seems

Answer (score 1):

There's one or more rows that have a bad character in the XML.

Run this to confirm:

```
SELECT convert(xml, A.[business_line])
FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A;
```

If you still see an error you can track down the bad rows using `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` like this.

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(xml, A.[business_line])
FROM [EU_OTH_REG].[dbo].[TBL_EU_OTH_TXN_REG_RSDS] A
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, A.[business_line]) IS NULL;
```